# how to create a view with SUM or AVG depend on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

I want to get the **same result** even if I add a column in the **GROUP BY** section or not for this case : 
I have a table that contains sale_id,product_id, command quantity and delivered quantity 
 
I want to get sum of command quantity if the grouping by product_id
data

```
CREATE TABLE sale_delivery ( id serial unique , sale_id INTEGER, product_id INTEGER, sale_qty Float, delivered_qty Float ); 
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(106827,3063,3135,1100.000,44.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(106828,3063,3155,400.000,11.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(106958,3063,3155,400.000,44.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(106959,3063,3135,1100.000,374.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(107646,3063,3135,1100.000,143.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(108871,3063,3135,1100.000,143.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(108872,3063,3155,400.000,44.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(109127,3063,3155,400.000,44.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(109128,3063,3135,1100.000,143.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(109627,3063,3135,1100.000,187.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(109628,3063,3155,400.000,44.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(109682,3063,3135,1100.000,66.0);
INSERT INTO sale_delivery VALUES(110103,3063,3155,400.000,213.0);
```

here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    sale_id,
    COUNT(product_id),
    SUM(sale_qty)/COUNT(product_id) sale_qty ,
    SUM(delivered_qty) deliveryed_qty
--  AVG(sale_qty) sale_qty,
--  SUM(deliveryed_qty ) deliveryed_qty, 
FROM sale_delivery 
WHERE sale_id=3063
GROUP BY sale_id
      ,product_id
```

But if I comment the last line I get the result as an **AVG** of **count(*)** *not* **count(product_id)** !! 
here is the link of the query 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cd9d9/2

I want to get the **same result** without the last line `,product_id`

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you would like to achieve.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added it in the last line

Comment: if you want same result then why you remove last line. ?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale because the requirement of the platform where I want to use it

Comment: I can see there is a good question underneath the badly worded text. Just rearrange the text.

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT sale_id, avg(product_idCNT), SUM(sale_qty)/COUNT(product_id) sale_qty , SUM(delivered_qty) deliveryed_qty
  FROM 
  (
SELECT 
 sale_id,
 COUNT(product_id) as product_idCNT,
 sum(sale_qty) as sale_qty,
 COUNT(product_id) as product_id,
 SUM(delivered_qty) AS delivered_qty
FROM sale_delivery 
WHERE sale_id=3063
GROUP BY sale_id
    
  

   )p

   GROUP BY sale_id
```

Comment: I tried that it looks like the count(product_id)  = count(*) !!